# Specifying optional arguments with variables

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, optional-arguments

Perhaps this is poor programming on my part, but I would like to create a function that uses a variable as an optional parameter:

```
var = 2;
f[a_:var] := {a}
```

The desired output would be:

```
f[]
(* {2} *)
var = 5;
f[]
(* {5} *)
```

However the optional `a` maintains the value of `var` when `f` was defined:

```
var = 2;
f[a_:var] := {a}
var = 5;
f[]
(* {2} *)
f[5]
(* {5} *)
```

I can work around this somewhat by making the optional value dynamic:

```
var = 2;
f[a_:Dynamic[var]] := {a}
f[];
(* {2} *)
var = 5;
(* Above output updates to 5 *)
```

I can imagine having some fun with this type of behavior, but it is not what I want at the moment.  Is it possible to set an optional parameter that can be updated?  I'll also happily accept an answer that tells me why this would be a bad idea.

Comment: It is not what you are asking for but it does the same thing: `f[x_]:={x}; f[]:={a};`

Comment: All you have to do is to define your function before `var` has any value, or use `Block`, such as `Block[{var}, f[a_:var]:={a}]`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661583/mathematica-set-default-value-for-argument-to-nonconstant/4661633#4661633) and a discussion in comments below it.

Comment: Related FYI: `Default` *appears* to allow variable values, [but it does not.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6337753/618728)  You may already know this, but it's tripped up quite a few users I believe.  Also, I see that [Simon](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34/simon) (I miss his participation) posted effectively the same method that Leonid just showed in answer to that old question of mine.

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: [(26354)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26354/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible to do, in at least two ways. The first method is to make sure that your function's definition is entered first, so that the default variable `var` has no value yet:

```
ClearAll[var,f];
f[a_: var] := {a};
var = 2;

f[]

(* {2}  *)

var = 5;
f[]

(* {5}  *)
```

The second method would work regardless of whether or not the variable `var` has currently a value:

```
ClearAll[var, f];
var = 2;
Block[{var}, f[a_: var] := {a}]
```

and then again:

```
f[]

(* {2}  *)

var = 5;
f[]

(* {5}  *)
```

The reason this works is that what matters is only what `var` evaluates to at the moment of definition. It is then being evaluated by `SetDelayed`, and its value is what is being used to form the resulting global rule. Once that global rule (definition) has been added to the global rule base, it does not matter any more what happens to `var` after that.

A closely related discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661583/mathematica-set-default-value-for-argument-to-nonconstant/). A question of whether or not to actually use such constructs is a matter of taste. I don't see a good reason to not recommend ever using it. If you use the `Block`-based method, then it should be reasonably safe. Usual warnings related to the use of global variables do apply, but I do acknowledge that there may be cases where such construct may be justified.

Comment: Thanks - your discussion makes perfect sense, and makes me think I should have figured this one out myself!

Comment: @bobthechemist Glad I could help, and thanks for the accept. I think this was the fastest accept for any of my answers - within 3 minutes of posting the answer :). You could have waited for some time with accepting though, to encourage others to contribute more answers. As for the subject matter, this actually seems to be one of these issues which look very simple once we know the answer, but actually are not so simple. I seem to remember that it took me some time to figure this out when I asked myself the same question, back when I didn't know the answer.

Comment: I was been playing with and being frustrated by this just last week. You're right, obvious, once you know the answer.

Comment: @rcollyer Well, sorry to hear that. The answer was also on SO, but my version was only in comments to Brett's answer, and one has to remember which question was that. In fact, since it was in comments, it took me some time to find that discussion now. I only managed to do find it because I remembered who posted one of the answers to that question (Brett).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I do typically try to hold off accepting answers so that others may comment, but yours hit the nail right on the head so I figured I would accept and move on.

Comment: @bobthechemist Well, thanks in any case, good that it helped. This was one of the questions that would have to pop up here on SE sooner or later.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin ha, it seems they are popping up rather sooner than later lately :) Maybe if you are anticipating couple more  then you can post some Q&A :)

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, I don't have as much time these days as I used to :). When I happen to pass by and have some time, and *if* I believe that my answer can add something, I answer. Sometimes, I answer when I feel that I know the answer and that there may also be incorrect or incomplete answers, because the subject matter is tricky or something. And sometimes, I answer when there is a question for which I either have some code from the past, or which interests me in its own right. So, let's wait for more questions :).

Comment: I hope you didn't get me wrong. I do understand this, also I wouldn't dare suggest a stranger to work for free :) It was just quick reference to that old comment.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Is `HoldPattern` incorrect to use? (see my answer)

Comment: @QuantumDot I guess that's a possibility I overlooked. Upvoted your answer. What really matters here, is how the rule enters the rule base. We want to keep `var` symbolic there. All the methods we described do accomplish this, in different ways.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use `HoldPattern`:

```
var = 2;
HoldPattern[f[a_: var]] := {a};
```

Then:

```
f[]
(* 2 *)
```

And then:

```
var = 5;
f[]
(* 5 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, here is another way:

```
var = 2;
DownValues[f] = HoldPattern[f[a_ : var]] :> {a};
```

Now

```
f[]
```

> ```
> {2}
> ```

and

```
var = 5;
f[]
```

> ```
> {5}
> ```