# How to write a `HeldOptional` variant of `Optional` that does not evaluate its second argument?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, optional-arguments

[How to specify optional arguments that take functional values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/how-to-specify-optional-arguments-that-take-functional-values/123387#123387) made me wonder: Can we come up with a variant of `Optional` that allows to do the following:

```
lhs = x_;
g[lhs~HeldOptional~RandomReal[]] := x
DownValues@g
```

and get

`{HoldPattern[g[Optional[x_, RandomReal[]]]] :> x}`

Specifically, I want `HeldOptional` to evaluate the left hand side like all pattern construction constructs, while leaving the right argument untouched.

The following attempt does not work:

```
HeldOptional~SetAttributes~HoldRest
HeldOptional[x_, y_] := Optional[x, Unevaluated@y]
```

This gives the DownValue

`{HoldPattern[g[x_ : Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]]] :> x}`

such that `g[]` gives `Unevaluated[RandomReal[]]` instead of a random real.

Comment: This is also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29013/specifying-optional-arguments-with-variables?rq=1

Comment: I guess one way to start would be to overload `x:SetDelayed[___]/;!FreeQ[x,HeldOptional]:=...` to automate what QuantumDot suggested.

Comment: `HeldOptional = Function[, HoldPattern@Optional[#1, #2], HoldRest]`?

Comment: @jkuczm `HoldPattern`, of course! Please post an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting together idea from question to use function with [`HoldRest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html) attribute, together with idea from [QuantumDot's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124254/14303) to use [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) we get:

```
ClearAll[HeldOptional]
HeldOptional~SetAttributes~HoldRest
HeldOptional[x_, y_] := HoldPattern@Optional[x, y]
```

`HoldPattern` wraps whole [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) pattern, but since function has only `HoldRest` attribute, its firs argument evaluates before it's passed to held pattern.

Using `HeldOptional` we get definitions equivalent to requested one:

```
ClearAll[lhs, g]
lhs = x_;
g[lhs~HeldOptional~RandomReal[]] := x
DownValues@g
(* {HoldPattern[g[HoldPattern[x_ : RandomReal[]]]] :> x} *)
```

and desired behavior:

```
g[a]
(* a *)
g[]
(* 0.408798 *)
g[]
(* 0.0652214 *)
g[]
(* 0.587329 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
ClearAll[DontEvaluateInOptional];
DontEvaluateInOptional~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
DontEvaluateInOptional /: (h: Except[Optional])[l___, 
   HoldPattern@DontEvaluateInOptional[b___], r___] := h[l, r, b];

HeldOptional~SetAttributes~HoldRest
HeldOptional[x_, y_] := Optional[x, DontEvaluateInOptional@y]

lhs = x_;
g[lhs~HeldOptional~RandomReal[]] := x
DownValues@g

g[3]
g[]
g[]
```

> Out[39]= {HoldPattern[g[x_:DontEvaluateInOptional[RandomReal[]]]]:>x}
>
> Out[40]= 3
>
> Out[41]= 0.0769485
>
> Out[42]= 0.674345

This is a bit superior to the `Unevaluated` method I suggested first because it is stripped in more cases, but it cannot insert the default value into HoldAllComplete symbols:

```
ClearAll[f,g];
f~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete
g[x_~HeldOptional~RandomReal[]] := f[x]
g[3]
g[]
```

> Out[46]= f[3]
>
> Out[47]= f[DontEvaluateInOptional[RandomReal[]]]

Comment: and for `HoldAll` symbols, the default is inserted unevaluated which may or may not be what you want